# How can I extend coderay to highlight a new language?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting

A syntax highlighter gem named [coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) seems to have a good reputation [among similar tools](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/syntax_highlighting) (based on the number of downloads and releases). Its home page provides many examples named [rays](http://coderay.rubychan.de/rays).

My source language is not present in the list of lexers (aka scanners in coderay). It seems that the lexers extend [StringScanner](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html) gem. How can I add a language to coderay?

Comment: I would start with reading existing scanners

Comment: sure but I'd like to have the general guidelines. The scanners are so different.

Comment: What language do you want to scan?

Comment: I'd like to scan VHDL. I know the syntax very well (I developed compilers for it). Bit I though it would be trivial to get html for it, using third-party tools. Btw, maybe coderay is not the right choice (?)